# Connect Apache Airflow Server to a secure PostgreSQL instance

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, airflow

We have to connect Apache Airflow to a secure PostgreSQL instance. We therefore changed the configuration setting and added the parameters like in the example below:

```
[core]
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@192.168.0.1:5432/dbname?sslmode=verify-ca&sslrootcert=/root/osb-postgresql-server-ca.pem&sslcert=/root/osb-postgresql-client-cert.pem&sslkey=/root/osb-postgresql-client-key.pem
```

If we then run the following command:

```
airflow checkdb
```

We get the message:

```
[2020-08-27 14:59:03,317] {{db.py:430}} INFO - Connection successful.
```

If we run the this command:

```
airflow resetdb
```

We get this message:

```
This will drop existing tables if they exist. Proceed? (y/n)y
[2020-08-27 15:15:50,918] {{db.py:404}} INFO - Dropping tables that exist
[2020-08-27 15:15:51,408] {{settings.py:278}} DEBUG - Disposing DB connection pool (PID 3068)
```

And nothing really happens. We can't start tasks with **airflow test**

Does anybody know what might be the issue here?

Comment: did you try [`airflow initdb`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/initialize-database.html), it is mentioned on [quick start page](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/start.html)? You can read about [differences b/w `initdb` & `resetdb`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59560731/3679900) and find the complete CLI reference [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli-ref)

Comment: Yes we did that as well, but to no avail. What's more disturbing is that ```airflow list_dags``` works. But ```airflow test dag_name task_name 2020-08-27``` does not work. If we connect to the same DB non secure everything works fine.

Comment: Do you have some kind of log you get from your `airflow test` cmd? Also just to be clear, you have a standalone airflow?