# Auto rerun DAGs after certain time

Tags: airflow

We have a process that runs everyday and kicks of several DAGs and subtags. something like:
(1) Master controller --> (11) DAGs --> (11*5) Child DAGs --> (11*5*4) Tasks

if something failed on any particular day, we want to do retry the next day. Similarly, we want to retry all failed dags over the last 10 days (to successfully complete them automatically).

Is there a way to automate this retry process?

Answer (score 0):

(until now) **Airflow doesn't natively support** rerunning failed `DAG`s (Failed `task`s within a DAG can of course [be retried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55956022/3679900))

The premise could've been that

- tasks are retried anyways;
- so if even then the DAG fails, then the workflow might require human-intervention

---

But as always, you can build it (a [custom-operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/custom-operator.html) or simply [`PythonOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/python.html))

1. Determine failed `DagRun`s in your specified time-period (last 10 days or whatever)

   - by either using [`DagRun` `SQLAlchemy` model](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dagrun.py) (you can check [`views.py` for reference](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/caa60b1141ac02cdde1c33464be9adca114c2ed5/airflow/www/views.py#L429))
   - or by directly querying the [`dag_run` table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55268690/3679900) in Airflow's backend meta-db
2. Trigger those failed DAGs using [`TriggerDagRunOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.html)

And then create and schedule this *retry-orchestrator* DAG (that runs daily / whatever frequency you need) to re-trigger failed DAGs of past 10-days

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and proposed solution. Will give it a try and let you know if it worked or need some more guidance on it.